# Joining two table with SUM of Column and Group by another column

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

Need help to join and group with SUM() function two tables. 

The Tables are as under:

```
DEBIT TABLE                 CREDIT TABLE                
---------------------       ---------------------
CustomerName    Debit       CustomerName    Credit
---------------------       ---------------------
Customer1       200.00      Customer1       100.00
Customer1       300.00      Customer1       100.00
Customer2       100.00      Customer1       100.00
Customer2       600.00      Customer2       200.00
-----------------------     Customer2       300.00
                            Customer2       50.00
                            -----------------------
```

I need to show the two Join table as:

```
JOIN TABLE(DEBIT CREDIT TABLE)              
------------------------------------------
CustomerName    Debit   Credit  Closing
------------------------------------------
Customer1       500.00  300.00  200.00
Customer2       700.00  550.00  150.00
------------------------------------------
```

This is as far as I am getting but doesn't yield the right result:

```
"SELECT Debit_Tbl.CustomerName, SUM(Debit_Tbl.Debit) as Debit, SUM(Credit_Tbl.Credit) as Credit, SUM(Debit_Tbl.Debit) - SUM(Credit_Tbl.Credit) as Closing from Debit_Tbl LEFT OUTER JOIN Credit_Tbl ON Debit_Tbl.CustomerName = Credit_Tbl.CustomerName GROUP BY Debit_Tbl.debit UNION SELECT Debit_Tbl.CustomerName, SUM(Debit_Tbl.Debit) as Debit, SUM(Credit_Tbl.Credit) as Credit, SUM(Debit_Tbl.Debit) - SUM(Credit_Tbl.Credit) as Closing from Debit RIGHT OUTER JOIN Credit_Tbl ON Debit_Tbl.CustomerName = Credit_Tbl.CustomerName GROUP BY Debit_Tbl.debit"
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you tried with some subquery for the summed value?

Comment: Try starting with something like this... SELECT customername,debit * -1 amnt FROM debit_table UNION SELECT customername,credit FROM credit_table;

Answer (score 1):

Your query is producing a cartesian product between the two tables.  Instead, use `union all` to separate the debits and credits into separate columns -- without multiplying the number of rows.  Then do the aggregation:

```
select customerName, sum(debit) as debit, sum(credit) as credit,
       sum(debit) - sum(credit) as closing
from (select d.customerName, debit as debit, 0 as credit
      from debit d
      union all
      select c.customerName, 0 as debit, credit
      from credit c
     ) cd
group by customerName;
```

Comment: In the case of one table having more customer names than the other, what would be the easiest way to filter out where the customers did not match using your above query?

Comment: @Clint . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.  As a note, though, this returns all customer names in *either* table, so the two tables do not each need to have all the customers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT customerName,
  debit,
  credit,
  debit-credit AS closing
FROM
  (SELECT d.CustomerName AS customerName,
    SUM(d.debit)         AS debit,
    SUM(c.credit)        AS credit
  FROM debit d
  INNER JOIN credit c
  ON d.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
  )
```